# UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication kills postback

Tags: single-sign-on, postback

I am trying to include SSO with office 365 for one of our web applications.
the problem is that as soon as SSO is working all my postbacks are getting ignored.

what I did was the following,
I installed those Nuget Packages
- Microsoft.Owin
- Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
- Microsoft.Owin.Security
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect
- Owin

I created an app in my AAD
then I've added some settings to my web.config

```html
    <add key="ida:PostRedirectUri" value="http://localhost:4439" />
    <add key="ida:ClientId" value="XXXXXXX" />
    <add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/" />
    <add key="ida:Tenant" value="XXXX.onmicrosoft.com" />
    <add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="http://localhost:4439" />
```

and I added Startup.vb to my solution with the following content

```
 app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions())
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions() With {
        .ClientId = clientId,
        .Authority = authority
    })
    app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate)
```

and after this the SSO works however al postbacks on buttons fail
if I click a button the page just gets reloaded.
also the IsPostBack parameter is alwayst false.

What I found was that when I remove the "app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication" part, postbacks are working again, but SSO is not.
how can I make sure my postbacks are working and I can also use UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication ?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue,
in my web.config I had

<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
in system.web
removing the key "runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests" solved the problem
<modules>